# Problem with jsp file references on login page in Struts 2

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I'm using Struts 2 and having an odd problem on the login page. I have this specified as the welcome file in web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

where all the jsp files are in that jsp subdirectory in WEB-INF. There are also some images and a css file in their own folders (`images` and `styles` respectively) also in WEB-INF. The problem comes in referring to those images and the css file in the jsp pages. On the other pages, I have references like

```
<img src="../images/army-logo.svg" alt="logo" />
```

...which works just fine. However, if I use the same relative reference on the login page, it only works if I arrive at the page as the result of a Struts action; when I first land on the page (my typing in the root without any of the page material, e.g. `http://localhost/project/`, it cannot find these files, and will only work if I references them as

```
<img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
```

I tried the obvious solution of moving the login page down a level to reside directly in WEB-INF and adjusting all the references to it accordingly, which got me the dreaded "There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path" error. I also tried doing a `<jsp:forward>` from a new welcome page, which fails the same way: it's still interpreting the login page as if it were in a different folder. How do I organize these files and fix the references so they work under both cases?

Comment: You stop using relative paths.

Comment: What's the root for absolute references, then?

Comment: `"/"`. You can't put publicly-accessible artifacts under `WEB-INF`; browsers can't access that directory by default, e.g., when the browser tries to find `WEB-INF/images/foo.jpg` it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for future reference, I have worked out what is going on. The references to images and css are happening in the browser, so they need to be referenced absolutely in the same way that page URLs appear in the browser. References within Struts, however, start one folder further out the tree, which typically in a development environment means that the Struts root is WEB-INF.